# ASP.NET MVC3 CSS framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css-frameworks

I'm wondering, which css framework is best suitable for ASP.NET MVC 3?
I've tried [yaml](http://www.yaml.de/en/) and it has several drawbacks in my opinion, at least using with ASP.NET MVC 3:

1. uses inputs for buttons by default (so, not compatible with jquery ui, because jquery ui uses buttons in dialogs for example).
2. you need to adjust css for ASP.NET MVC 3 validation.
3. I don't like how they describe forms (well that is may be only my
   subjective opinion regarding this, anyway you need to use custom
   editors if you wish stick to yaml css style).
4. some css class names are not very intuitive.

Nothing, that would be show stoppers, but maybe there's better alternative - something, that is adapted for ASP.NET MVC specifics, or may be ASP.NET MVC project stub, adapted to yaml css framework.

Update: [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) looking good, is lightweight and good structured, worth checking out.
Update 2: TwitterBootstrap is getting popular too, you can get it for asp.net mvc here http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used both Blueprint (http://www.blueprintcss.org/)  and 960Grid (http://960.gs/) quite successfully with MVC.

But more recently I am leaning towards "BlueLess" (https://github.com/michaek/blueless) - a ".LESS" (http://lesscss.org/) version of Blueprint together with the simply excellent "Chirpy" (http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)  VS2010 add-in which automagically converts and minimises CSS, Javascript, LESS, CoffeeScript etc. quite transparently. A simply wonderful tool.

Both Blueprint and 960Grid are for layout and typography ... for form design/styling I would look at the standard JQuery UI framework (http://jqueryui.com/) .. or *perhaps* the Telerik MVC Extensions (http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx)

Hope this helps.